# Reject 'null' values in a JSON collection

Tags: c#, json.net

Is it possible to configure Json.NET to throw an exception when it finds a *null* value in a JSON array?

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var json = @"
        {
          ""values"": [
            ""first"",
            ""second"",
            null,
            ""last""
          ]
        }";

        // Can I make this throw a serialization exception?
        var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
    }
}

public class RootObject
{
    // This should never be null and never contain null
    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
    public List<string> Values { get; set; }
}
```

I looked at *JsonArrayAttribute.AllowNullItems* but couldn't figure out how to use it. https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonArrayAttribute_AllowNullItems.htm

Answer (score 1):

Implement a setter function which reject the set when the value contains a Null element :)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a built-in way to do it, but a little more manual approach of using a custom `JsonConverter` could do the trick.

```cs
public class DisallowNullItemsConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        => serializer.Serialize(writer, value);

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue,
        JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var deserialized = serializer.Deserialize(reader, objectType);
        if (deserialized is IEnumerable items && items.Cast<object>().Any(x => x is null))
        {
            const string errorMessage = "No nulls allowed round these parts...";
            if (reader is IJsonLineInfo lineInfo)
            {
                throw new JsonReaderException(errorMessage,
                    reader.Path,
                    lineInfo.LineNumber,
                    lineInfo.LinePosition,
                    null);
            }

            throw new JsonReaderException(errorMessage);
        }

        return deserialized;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        => typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(objectType) && objectType != typeof(string);
}
```

Use like this:

```cs
public class RootObject
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(DisallowNullItemsConverter))]
    public List<string> Values { get; set; }
}
```